# C# .Net Core 3.1 SPA - how to make middleware work only for a single path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

**How to make middleware work only for a single path ?**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#branch-the-middleware-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UseWhen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usewhenextensions.usewhen). For example:

```cs
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("branch"),
                       HandleBranchAndRejoin);
```

Reference: [Branch the middleware pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/#branch-the-middleware-pipeline)